# Is there a test framework for C that forces race conditions?

Tags: c, concurrency

Does there exist a test framework for C that forces race conditions?

Or for C++ and Java, for that matter.

Comment: Have an upvote for a great question!

Comment: [Corensic Jinx](http://www.corensic.com/Products.aspx).  I have not used it and thus cannot comment on its utility or effectiveness.

Comment: Great question, but in general the finest-grained race conditions are too difficult to hit for a general tool to do a good job at it. For instance glibc/NPTL has some nasty race conditions that have been reported and ignored, which would probably take tens or hundreds of years to hit on a single machine. Of course they've probably been hit many times already in Google's or Facebook's data centers.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Valgrind tool [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) detects (among other things) data races in C or C++ programs that use pthreads.

Comment: drd is another tool for detecting data races.

Comment: Thanks; also [ThreadSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizerVsOthers)

Comment: For some reason, Helgrind was reporting races concerning errno, although errno is supposed to be thread-local. I tried ThreadSanitizer, and it worked pretty well. It even comes with [RaceVerifier](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/RaceVerifier) to confirm the reports logged by ThreadSanitizer.